# Do the cumulative density and distribution functions refer to the same thing?

Tags: probability-theory

Read an article referring to the "joint cumulative density function (CDF) of the d , independent, U[0,1] distribution functions" [1] and got confused.

[1] http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/sgf2008/copulas.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abbreviation cdf stands for *cumulative distribution function*.  It definitely does **not** stand for ["cumulative density function."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_density_function)